# C - Dynamic Array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to feed an array with fscanf() while looping through a file containing a list of integers, n integers long. It seems that I need to use malloc and/or potentially realloc. I've heard that the malloc command takes a noticeable amount of execution time and that it's best to over-allocate. Would someone mind helping me out with understanding the building blocks of accomplishing this end?

**Disclaimer: I'm new to C.**

Comment: `I've heard`. I think you need to take your time and read a little about dynamic allocation. There's a bunch of tutorials out there. Don't be afraid.

Comment: **Claimer:** You will not notice the execution time of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, what you've heard is misleading (at least to me). `malloc` is a just a function, and usually a fast one.

- Most of the time it does all of its job in user-space. It "overallocates" so you don't have to
- The bookkeeping (the linked list with free blocks etc.) is highly optimized since virtually everyone uses `malloc`

It's unrealistic to think you can easily beat `malloc` at this game. I am sorry if this doesn't answer your question (which was pretty general) but you have to realize there is no (<strike>spoon</strike>) optimization you can easily implement.

Comment: `malloc is a just a function`, Well it is one of the most important functions so i would not say it is `just` a function. :)

Comment: @Als I hear you :-) I meant it as in "not a system call".

Comment: Disagree.  Malloc, depending on how it's implemented is not usually a fast function.  Quite often, it is a 10 top performance hog, depending on how many blocks you are tracking.  It all depends on how the list of blocks internally is handled, though usually it is a O(n) or worse exectuon time to add or remove items.  If OP is doing a malloc within a while loop, there is a strong chance that he will feel the overhead, though not when coupled with an IO function such as fscanf.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan You may be right, but the cost of the work done to find out the needed size might be prohibitive. Now, if he said he wants to `realloc` as he goes, well that's another question.

Comment: realloc - gah!  I had to implement that the other day on an embedded device due to a very poor lib we inherited.  That function is an ugly way to manage memory.  Fragmentation - check.  Mem moving constantly - check.  Error prone - check.  A trifecta of badness.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: one needs to start worrying about all this when one has lots of small objects that are freed as often as they are malloced. For the task at hand it does not matter at all.

Answer (score 6):

Reading the file will be much slower than allocating the memory!

You may want to read the whole file and find out how many entires you want and then malloc() all in one go.

malloc(sizeof(int)*n)

Comment: This is a much better way to handle your memory allocation.  Even better if you can get a filesize() before the read to pre-allocate the whole buffer once.

Comment: This is an awesome piece of advice. Thank you.

Comment: So...the suggestion is that the file be read twice?  Once to find out how long it is and again to store it?  That makes sense if performance is not a primary concern.

Answer (score 4):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil (google it).

That said, allocate whatever amount you guess is reasonable/typical for the task at hand, and double it whenever you have to realloc. This strategy is rather hard to beat.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, malloc isn't going to cause you issues.  The run time of fscanf will be many, many times slower than the overhead of malloc and free.  But, it can add up in high performance areas of an app.  In these areas, there are other ways such as mem pools and fixed size allocators than can combat malloc()'s overhead.  But, you are no where near needing to worry about performance overhead when you are just starting out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `malloc()` adds some overhead to each allocation to maintain its internal data structures (at least 4 bytes in common implementations), so if you integers are 4 bytes long, doing a `malloc()` for each integer would have >= 50% overhead (probably 75%). This would be the equivalent of using an array of `Integer`'s in Java, instead of an array of `int`'s.

As @Charles Dowd said, it's much better to allocate all the memory in one go, to avoid overhead.

Comment: Not to mention that doing a function call for every integer in what could be a very large file is likely to be a bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to call `malloc` or `realloc` with every integer read, that's for sure.  Can you estimate how much space you will need?  Do you control the file format?  If so, you could have the first line of the file be a single integer that denotes how many integers are to be read from the file.  Then you could allocate all the space you need in one go.  If you don't control the format and can't do this, follow the other suggestion mentioned in this thread: allocate a reasonably-sized buffer, and double it every time you run out of space.

Answer (score 0):

It's a text file (not binary) and not in a fixed format, right? Otherwise it would be easy to calculate the size of the array from the file size ( `buffer_size = file_size / record_size` , buffersize is in words (the size of an int), the other sizes is in bytes).

This is what I would do (but I'm a bit of a nutter when it comes to applied statistics).

1) What is the maximum number of characters (a.k.a. bytes) a number (a.k.a. record) will occupy in the file, don't forget to include the end-of-line characters (CR, NF) and other blank glyphs (spaces, tabs et.c.)? If you already can estimate what the average size of a record would be, then it is even better, you use that instead of the maximum size.

```
initial_buffer_size = file_size / max_record_size + 1    (/ is integer division)
```

2) Allocate that buffer, read your integers into that buffer until it is full. If the whole file is read then you are finished, otherwise resize or reallocate buffer to meet your new estimated needs.

```
resize_size = 
   prev_buffer_size
   + bytes_not_read / ( bytes_already_read / number_of_records_already_read ) 
   + 1
```

3) Read into that buffer (from where the previous reading ended) until it is full, or all the of file has been read.

4) If not finished, repeat from step 2) with the new `prev_buffer_size`.

This will work best if the numbers (records) are totally randomly distributed from a byte-size point of view. If not, and if you have a clue what kind of distribution they have, you can adjust the algorithm according to that.